# Display a MsgBox when any value in a column matches specified value

Tags: excel, vba, boolean

I want to display a MsgBox when

- any value of the "I" column is equal to "*"
- any value of the "AT" column equals "Inexistente"

I receive errors.

All the values in the columns are strings

```
Sub Booluno()
Dim concepto As Excel.Range
Set concepto = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Base 2019").Range("AT6:AT1040")

Dim valoresconcepto As String
valoresconcepto = concepto.Value

Dim request As Excel.Range
Set request = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Base 2019").Range("I6:I1040")

Dim valoresrequest As String
valoresrequest = request.Value

Dim Bool As Boolean

If valoresconcepto = "Inexistente" And valoresrequest <> "*" Then
    Bool = True

ElseIf valoresconcepto = "Inexistente" And valoresrequest = "*" Then
    Bool = False
    
End If

If Bool = True Then
    MsgBox "Ojo, Hay nuevos conceptos por agregar para los requerimientos"
    
    If Bool = False Then
        MsgBox "No hay nuevos conceptos por añadir, puedes subir el archivo a nuestra carpeta una vez termines :)"
    
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting. Also, properly indent your code to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are problematic:

```
valoresconcepto = concepto.Value
```

and

```
valoresrequest = request.Value
```

Since `concepto` and `request` are multi-cell ranges, their `.Value`s are 2D Variant arrays, not `String`s.

One option to simplify is to use `WorksheetFunction.CountIfs` or its late-bound form, `Application.CountIfs`, using `~` to escape the `*`.

```
If Application.CountIfs(concepto, "Inexistente") > 0 Then
    If Application.CountIfs(request, "~*") = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Ojo, Hay nuevos conceptos por agregar para los requerimientos"
    Else
        MsgBox "No hay nuevos conceptos por añadir, puedes subir el archivo a nuestra carpeta una vez termines :)"
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop:

```
For i = 1 to request.Rows.Count
    if concepto.Cells(i, 1).Value = "*" Then
        Msg box("blah blah 1")
        Exit For
    EndIf

    if request.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Inexistante" Then
        Msg box("blah blah 2")
        Exit For
    EndIf
Next
```